# DevExpress GridView Summary Update Sum Footer When 2nd Row Added

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

My GridView Summary on Footer not updated when I add First Row.

My Code

```
Item.SummaryType = SummaryItemType.Count
    Item.DisplayFormat = "{0} Item"

    TotalPrice.SummaryType = SummaryItemType.Sum

    DataTabel = New DataTable

    With DataTabel
        .Columns.Add("ItemCode")
        .Columns.Add("ItemName")
        .Columns.Add("Category")
        .Columns.Add("Quantity", GetType(Decimal))
        .Columns.Add("Unit")
        .Columns.Add("PriceCode")
        .Columns.Add("Price", GetType(Double))
        .Columns.Add("TotalPrice", GetType(Double), "Quantity * Price")
    End With

    GridControl1.DataSource = DataTabel

    With GridView1
        .OptionsView.NewItemRowPosition = Views.Grid.NewItemRowPosition.Bottom
        .OptionsView.ShowFooter = True
        .OptionsCustomization.AllowColumnMoving = False
        .OptionsCustomization.AllowSort = False
        .OptionsSelection.EnableAppearanceFocusedRow = False

        .Columns(0).Caption = "Code Item"
        .Columns(0).ColumnEdit = RepoKodeBarang

        .Columns(1).Caption = "Item Name"
        .Columns(1).OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(1).OptionsColumn.TabStop = False
        .Columns(1).OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = False

        .Columns(2).Caption = "Category"
        .Columns(2).OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(2).OptionsColumn.TabStop = False
        .Columns(2).OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = False

        .Columns(3).Caption = "Quantity"
        .Columns(3).ColumnEdit = RepoQuantity
        .Columns(3).Summary.Add(Item)

        .Columns(4).Caption = "Unit"
        .Columns(4).OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(4).OptionsColumn.TabStop = False
        .Columns(4).OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = False

        .Columns(5).Caption = "Price Code"
        .Columns(5).ColumnEdit = RepoKodeHarga
        .SetRowCellValue(GridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "PriceCode", 3)

        .Columns(6).Caption = "Price"

        .Columns(7).Caption = "Total Price"
        .Columns(7).OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(7).OptionsColumn.TabStop = False
        .Columns(7).OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = False
        .Columns(7).Summary.Add(TotalPrice)
    End With
```

If I add First Row, With Total Price Are 5.000 the summary still show blank, but if I add second row with Total Price 2.500 the summary will work and change to 7.500..

[Screenshot After 1st Row Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSKOD.png)

[Screenshot After 2nd Row Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MadJ3.png)

Did I miss something?

And by the way. All input happen in cell directly. Thanks

**Update #01** - If I Change the SummaryType to Count. It Will Work After 1st Row Added. But if I change back to Sum. It Doesnt Work.

**Update #02** - It does not work if I use

```
.Columns.Add("TotalPrice", GetType(Double), "Quantity * Price")
```

If I change to this, then it will works

```
.Columns.Add("TotalPrice", GetType(Double))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue and I solve it by using the Event:

> Gridview.ValidatingEditor

In my case i was checking if the input was Numeric with the code below:

```
Private Sub Gridview_ValidatingEditor(sender As Object, e As BaseContainerValidateEditorEventArgs) Handles Gridview.ValidatingEditor
              
        If Not IsNumeric(e.Value) Then
                e.Valid = False
                e.ErrorText = "Error"
        End If
End Sub
```